# Collapse search widget android

Tags: android, search, widget

I have implemented the search widget in the action bar following the official guide on the developers site of android. The widget starts in a collapsed state. When the user clicks on the search icon it expands and the keyboard pops up and the user can search. Once the user presses enter a new activity is launched on top that handles and displays the search. When the user press backs to return to the previous activity (before the search) I want that the search view would collapse automatically because the user just did a search. How does I do this? Now the user have to press the back key 2 after that, once to dismiss the keyboard and once to collapse the search widget. I have tried

```
searchManager.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
        public void onDismiss() {
            searchView.setIconified(true);
        }
    });
```

That collapses the keyboard but the user still have to press the back button once more to really collapse the view and move it back to its position in the actionbar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I have just come across it looking for the answer. I had tried exactly as above, but you actually need to collapse the MenuItem, not the SearchView. Here's the code snippet:-

```
 // I do this in onCreateOptionsMenu
 mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);

 // Call this when you want to collapse it
 mSearchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is by far the simplest, most elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Ryan's answer, but in case you have to support older version, you can do it with the **android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat**:

```
MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchMenuItem);
```